# Latex: How to insert vertical line divider on a certain cells in table?

Tags: tables

I am trying to add a vertical line in the first row between `X`  and `Y` that is consistent with the placement of the vertical line in the rows below. When I do `\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{3}{|l}{\textbf{Y}}` or `\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Y}}` the contents of the rows disappear. But these seem to be the solutions in other posts. Is there an easy fix?

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
  \usepackage{nicematrix}
  \usepackage{lineno}
  \usepackage{color, colortbl}
  \definecolor{aliceblue}{rgb}{0.94, 0.97, 1.0}
 \usepackage{float}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Y}} \\ \hline
      & \textbf{Region} & \textbf{r} & \textbf{$R^2$} & \textbf{p-value}& \textbf{r} & \textbf{$R^2$} & \textbf{p-value} \\ \hline
      \Block{4-1}{\rotate{\textbf{CLCH}}}
      & Ross Sea& -0.973 & 0.947 & 2.417 e-8  & -0.996 & 0.992 & 8.704 e-13\\
      & Amundsen-Bellingshausen Seas & -0.901 & 0.813 & 7.766 e-7& -0.637 & 0.406 & 0.006  \\
      & Antarctic Peninsula  & -0.607 & 0.369 & 0.009& -0.059 & 0.004 & 0.821 \\
      & Weddell Sea& -0.590 & 0.348 & 0.013 & -0.889 & 0.789 & 1.861 e-6  \\
      & East Antarctica & -0.954 & 0.910 & 2.953 e-9 & -0.975 & 0.952 & 2.619 e-11  \\ \hline \hline
      
      \Block{5-1}{\rotate{\textbf{CLCM}}}
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Ross Sea & 0.341 & 0.117 & 0.254 & 0.842 & 0.708 & 0.0003\\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Amundsen-Bellingshausen Seas  & 0.229 & 0.052 & 0.377 & 0.939 & 0.881 & 2.515 e-5 \\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Antarctic Peninsula & 0.719 & 0.517 & 0.001 & -0.824 & 0.679 & 4.734 e-5 \\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Weddell Sea & 0.817 & 0.668 & 6.204 e-5  & 0.708 & 0.501 & 0.001\\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & East Antarctica  & -0.372 & 0.138 & 0.141 & -0.414 & 0.172 & 0.098 \\ \hline
   \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{table} 

 \end{document}
```

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `|` at the end of the multicolumn specifications. The stuff between columns 'belongs' to the multicolumn preceding it.

```
 \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Y}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
  \usepackage{nicematrix}
  \usepackage{lineno}
  \usepackage{color, colortbl}
  \definecolor{aliceblue}{rgb}{0.94, 0.97, 1.0}
 \usepackage{float}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
     \hline
     & & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{X}} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{Y}} \\ \hline
      & \textbf{Region} & \textbf{r} & \textbf{$R^2$} & \textbf{p-value}& \textbf{r} & \textbf{$R^2$} & \textbf{p-value} \\ \hline
      \Block{4-1}{\rotate{\textbf{CLCH}}}
      & Ross Sea& -0.973 & 0.947 & 2.417 e-8  & -0.996 & 0.992 & 8.704 e-13\\
      & Amundsen-Bellingshausen Seas & -0.901 & 0.813 & 7.766 e-7& -0.637 & 0.406 & 0.006  \\
      & Antarctic Peninsula  & -0.607 & 0.369 & 0.009& -0.059 & 0.004 & 0.821 \\
      & Weddell Sea& -0.590 & 0.348 & 0.013 & -0.889 & 0.789 & 1.861 e-6  \\
      & East Antarctica & -0.954 & 0.910 & 2.953 e-9 & -0.975 & 0.952 & 2.619 e-11  \\ \hline \hline
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      \Block{5-1}{\rotate{\textbf{CLCM}}}
      & Ross Sea & 0.341 & 0.117 & 0.254 & 0.842 & 0.708 & 0.0003\\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Amundsen-Bellingshausen Seas  & 0.229 & 0.052 & 0.377 & 0.939 & 0.881 & 2.515 e-5 \\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Antarctic Peninsula & 0.719 & 0.517 & 0.001 & -0.824 & 0.679 & 4.734 e-5 \\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & Weddell Sea & 0.817 & 0.668 & 6.204 e-5  & 0.708 & 0.501 & 0.001\\
      \rowcolor{aliceblue}
      & East Antarctica  & -0.372 & 0.138 & 0.141 & -0.414 & 0.172 & 0.098 \\ \hline
   \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{table} 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. When I run it with the corrected line in Tex studio I get the desire result no problem but when I run that same code with the corrected line in Overleaf (my document is in Overleaf so ideally I need it to work in Overleaf) I get the following error : 'Package array Error: <{..} at wrong position: changed to !{..}.' for the line that you corrected ... and my output looks the same as the image I posted above. Is this an issue with Overleaf? Any thoughts?

Comment: @madschm Overleaf uses an old LaTeX installation. Apparently the 2020 version of `nicematrix` had an issue that was removed in the 2021 verison that I'm using locally. Locate the file `nicematrix.sty` on your computer (with texlive, you can try `kpsewhich nicematrix.sty`) and copy it to overleaf.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. For anyone viewing this answer later I saved the following file and uploaded it to my overleaf document: https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty?revision=56256&view=co

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tabularray` pacakge. If you want to use it in Overleaf, you need to download `tabularray.sty` and
`ninecolors.sty` first:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ninecolors

PS: you could use `siunitx` package to align numberic values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{aliceblue}{rgb}{0.94,0.97,1.0}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{tblr}{
     colspec = {|c|l|r|l|l|r|l|l|l|},
     row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries}, column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
     cell{1}{3,6} = {c=3}{l}, row{8-12} = {aliceblue},
     cell{3}{1} = {r=4}{c}, cell{8}{1} = {r=5}{c},
   }
     \hline
      &                              & X      &       &         & Y & & \\
     \hline
      & Region                       & r      & $R^2$ & p-value & r & $R^2$ & p-value \\
     \hline
      \rotatebox{90}{CLCH}
      & Ross Sea                     & -0.973 & 0.947 & 2.417 e-8  & -0.996 & 0.992 & 8.704 e-13 \\
      & Amundsen-Bellingshausen Seas & -0.901 & 0.813 & 7.766 e-7& -0.637 & 0.406 & 0.006  \\
      & Antarctic Peninsula          & -0.607 & 0.369 & 0.009& -0.059 & 0.004 & 0.821 \\
      & Weddell Sea                  & -0.590 & 0.348 & 0.013 & -0.889 & 0.789 & 1.861 e-6  \\
      & East Antarctica              & -0.954 & 0.910 & 2.953 e-9 & -0.975 & 0.952 & 2.619 e-11  \\
     \hline \hline
      \rotatebox{90}{CLCM}
      & Ross Sea                     & 0.341 & 0.117 & 0.254 & 0.842 & 0.708 & 0.0003 \\
      & Amundsen-Bellingshausen Seas & 0.229 & 0.052 & 0.377 & 0.939 & 0.881 & 2.515 e-5 \\
      & Antarctic Peninsula          & 0.719 & 0.517 & 0.001 & -0.824 & 0.679 & 4.734 e-5 \\
      & Weddell Sea                  & 0.817 & 0.668 & 6.204 e-5  & 0.708 & 0.501 & 0.001 \\
      & East Antarctica              & -0.372 & 0.138 & 0.141 & -0.414 & 0.172 & 0.098 \\
     \hline
   \end{tblr}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]